# Leaflet adding a HTML label

Tags: leaflet, labeling, html, css

I would like to add a HTML label above each marker in a leaflet map.

Is this possible? Example:

[image]

Code for labels:

HTML

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td class="red"></td>
        <td class="yellow"></td>
        <td class="orange"></td>
        <td class="blue"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

CSS

```
table{
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
td{    
    padding:20px;
    border:5px solid black;
}
.red{
    background-color:#F15E66;
}
.yellow{
    background-color:#FFDB64;
}
.orange{
    background-color:#F58326;
}
.blue{
    background-color:#85B1DE;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a plugin called Leaflet.label which does what you want: https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.label